# Mi expresión regular no encuentra cierto patrón en especifico en java

Tags: java

Hola buenas tardes amigos, espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, lo que pasa es que estoy intentando modificar una expresión, dicha expresión es el nombre del archivo que va a procesar, anteriormente traía esto:

```
String patron = "(fin|FIN)" + fechaConsulta + ".(txt|TXT)";
```

El codigo completo es el siguiente:

```
    public void archivo(String rutaBase, String rutaFin, String rutaGenerados, String rutaEnviados, Integer diaAConsultarArchivo, Calendar fechaActual, String rutaErrores, String rutaReenvio, int secuencia){
        String fechaConsulta = FORMATO_FECHA_CONTROL.format(fechaActual.getTime());
        //ffin20221210 se va a cambiar a Fin_sinimei_ffin2022121001 >
        //Fin_sinimei_AAAAMMDD01.TXT
        //Fin_sinimei_2022120801.txt
        
        //String patron = "(fin|FIN)" + fechaConsulta + ".(txt|TXT)";//este si lo toma
        //String patron = "(Fin_sinimei_)" + fechaConsulta + ".(txt|TXT)";//Nuevo patrón JJ revisar si funciona y toma nombre archivo
        
        String patron = "Fin_sinimei_" + fechaConsulta + ".txt";
        
        
        
        LOGGER.info((Object)("cadenas patrón..... " + patron));
        LOGGER.info((Object)("Se consultara el archivo " + patron));
//        SE COMENTA PARA TEST LA LLAMADA AL METODO DESCARGAARCHIVOSFTP, PERO EN PRODUCCIÓN SE DESCOMENTA
//        this.descargaArchivosFtp(patron);
        Map<String, String> lstArchivos = ArchivosUtil.obtenerListaArchivos(rutaBase, patron);
        if(lstArchivos.size() > 0) {
            LOGGER.info((Object)("Se encontraron " + lstArchivos.size() + " archivos de financiamiento"));
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> elementoArchivo : lstArchivos.entrySet()) {
                List<Fininfosap> registros = this.leerArchivo(elementoArchivo, rutaBase);
                   
                if(registros.isEmpty()) {
                    UtilidadEnvioCorreos.enviarCorreo("GAPUUid: Error de lectura archivo ", "El archivo no cumplen con el formato requerido y fue enviado a la carpeta de errores" , this.emailMapper.getDistribucionExcepcion());                      
                ArchivosUtil.moverArchivo(rutaBase, rutaErrores, elementoArchivo.getKey(),"","");
              
                LOGGER.info("El archivo inconsistente "+ elementoArchivo.getKey() +" fue enviado a la carpeta de errores " + "exitosamente" );//JJ
                }
                if (registros.size() <= 0) continue; 
                List<String> lstGenerados = this.generaArchivo(registros, elementoArchivo, rutaBase, secuencia);
                //ArchivosUtil.moverArchivo(rutaBase, rutaFin, elementoArchivo.getKey(),"","");
                //Cuando hace la generacion los manda a descargaSAP
                for (String archivoGenerado : lstGenerados) {
                    boolean resultado = ArchivosUtil.transfiereArchivoSFTP(rutaGenerados, archivoGenerado, this.param2.getUserDest(), this.param2.getPassDest(), this.param2.getHostDest(), this.param2.getPortDest(), this.param2.getRutaDest(), rutaBase);
                    //Aqui manda a procesados
                    if (!resultado) {
                        UtilidadEnvioCorreos.enviarCorreo("UpdateInvoiceNumber: Fallo en envio UpdateInvoiceNumber", "El proceso UpdateInvoiceNumber no ha podido enviar por ftp el archivo: " + archivoGenerado, this.emailMapper.getDistribucionExcepcion());
                        //continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        UtilidadEnvioCorreos.enviarCorreo("UpdateInvoiceNumber: Exito en envio UpdateInvoiceNumber ", "Se ha enviado el archivo: " + archivoGenerado + " Exitosamente ", this.emailMapper.getDistribucionExitoSubidaArchivo());
                        ArchivosUtil.moverArchivo(rutaGenerados, rutaEnviados, archivoGenerado,Constantes.COPYREENVIO, rutaReenvio);
                    }
                }
            } 
        }else {
            LOGGER.info((Object)("No se encontraron archivos de financiamiento para procesar"));
            UtilidadEnvioCorreos.enviarCorreo("GAPUUIDSAP - Archivos de financiamiento no encontrados ", "No se encontraron archivos para procesar" , this.emailMapper.getDistribucionExcepcion());
        }
        
        
        
        Map<String, String> lstArchivosPorEnviar = ArchivosUtil.obtenerListaArchivos(rutaGenerados, Constantes.PATRONFINEQ);
        for (String archivoPendiente : lstArchivosPorEnviar.keySet()) {
            boolean resultado = ArchivosUtil.transfiereArchivoSFTP(rutaGenerados, archivoPendiente, this.param2.getUserDest(), this.param2.getPassDest(), this.param2.getHostDest(), this.param2.getPortDest(), this.param2.getRutaDest(), rutaBase);
            if (!resultado) {
                UtilidadEnvioCorreos.enviarCorreo("GAPUUid: Fallo en envio fininfosap", "El proceso fininfosap no ha podido enviar por ftp el archivo: " + archivoPendiente, this.emailMapper.getDistribucionExcepcion());
                //continue;
            }
            ArchivosUtil.moverArchivo(rutaGenerados, rutaEnviados, archivoPendiente, Constantes.COPYREENVIO, rutaReenvio);
        }
       
    }
```

El método de arriba es básicamente leer información de un archivo y procesarla (esto ya lo hace) y lo toma en base a la expresión `String patron = "(fin|FIN)" + fechaConsulta + ".(txt|TXT)";`

Lo que quiero es cambiarle al siguiente nombre por ejemplo: Fin_sinimei_20221220123408.TXT y asi sucesivamente. lo unico que va a cambiar es en la HoraMinSeg, por lo que la aplicación ya los debería de tomar y hacer su trabajo, aqui el problema es la expresión que no lo toma, que es lo que podría hacer?

Actualmente le dejé lo siguiente: `String patron = "Fin_sinimei_" + fechaConsulta + ".txt";`

Pero no lo toma y no lo reconoce el archivo cosa que si existe, espero y puedan ayudarme con este problema, se los agradecería mucho, si algo no se entiende o haga falta con gusto lo pondré.

Actualización:

basandome en la respuesta de un desarrollador que me ayudó con una expresión regular realicé este regex: `Fin_sinimei_[0-9]+_[0-9]+\\.txt`

Pero en el log me sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es tomar esta información [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuantos mas archivos donde lo que va a cambiar es en la horaMinSeg, a que se deberá que la expresión no encuentre el archivo?

Actualización 2:

Esta expresión si la está tomando

```
String patron = "(finsinimei|FINSINIMEI)" + fechaConsulta + ".(txt|TXT)";
```

Por lo que al colocar el archivo con este nombre:
fin_sinimei20221221.txt si lo toma, como se ve a continuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces para que se vea mas completo y que tome mejor el archivo, como nombre tendría fin_sinimei_20221221_011009.txt (aquí pueden seguir viniendo mas archivo solo que va a cambiar la horaMinSeg, por ejemplo  fin_sinimei_20221221_121010.txt y así sucesivamente)

Así se vería el archivo en el servidor con el nombre correspondiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que con esto se pueda entender un poco mas. De antemano gracias.

Comment: ¿Cómo está declarado y asignado `FORMATO_FECHA_CONTROL`?

Comment: Hola, el formato está en yyyyMMdd fecha de hoy (20221220)

Answer (score 0):

Para que te sea mas fácil manejar la sensibilidad a mayúsculas usa las clases `Pattern` y `Matcher`:

```
String str = "Fin_sinimei_20221220_011009.txt";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "fin_sinimei_"+fechaConsulta+"_\\d{6}.txt"
                           , Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE
                           );
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
System.out.println(" "+m.matches());
```

Resultado:

```
 true
```

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, ya intenté con la expresión pero en el log se implrime como cadena por ejemplo _\\d{6}.txt, voy a actualizar mi pregunta en base a todas las pruebas que he hecho, espero que se pueda dar a entender mas